# Is the video processing of the ffmpeg transcoder done locally on my server?

Tags: files

When configuring the [Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video) module, I'm posed to choose either *ffmpeg* or *Zencoder* transcoder.

While it's clear that *Zencoder* leverages video transcoding cloud services by [Zencoder.com](https://zencoder.com), I wonder if the *ffmpeg* option here means video processing is done locally on my server?

In other words, does *ffmpeg* option use the computing power of my own server and therefore it's completely free?

Comment: Hi @kiamlaluno, what do you mean by "remove tags from title"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg is licensed under [GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) or [GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html), depending on compiling options. Both are free and open source.

As far as I see in the code (just glanced over it, mind), both [Video Presets](https://drupal.org/node/1218482) and [FFmpeg Converter](https://drupal.org/project/ffmpeg_converter) uses locally installed converter. Will it be free? Probably not. Looking on FFmpeg Converter page:

> **Note:** This module is not for beginners, since FFmpeg requires rather complicated server configuration.

Sysadmin's time usually isn't free, CPU power also is not. But you should be free from licence fees all right.